# Fetch Facebook User Name on External Website

Tags: facebook

How would i fetch a facebook users's name on my external website? So when they vist the site it would display their name without having to connect to facebook. Can it be fetched with a cookie or am i looking in the wrong area?

Comment: A user will **ALWAYS** have to authenticate your application before you know anything about him/her.  One does not simply *bypass* facebook authentication...

Answer (score 2):

You can't access any personally identifiable user data from Facebook without the user approving your application.  Liking a page does not count as approving an application.   So yes, you are looking in the wrong area.

Comment: The user has liked my facebook page and then is redirected to the website. IS it possible then?

Comment: definitely looking in the wrong area. Facebook has the cookie, you don't, so you need to talk to it (Facebook). Start with the javascript api and see how far you go.

Comment: Like != authorize.  You can only get ID and other user information after the user grants your app authorization to a list of permissions which they have the ability to revoke at any time.